# Visual Studio missing "Auto-sync Javascript References" menu item on _references.js file

Tags: visual-studio-2013

If I create a brand new MVC project in VS2013, I have a nice context menu on _references.js that allows me to manage auto-syncing of my js files. See below -

[image: auto-sync working]

In my existing MVC project, that contect menu doesn't include those items. See below -

[image: auto-sync not working]

I've compared the project files and don't see any glaring differences. So what could be causing this issue?

Comment: I have the exact same problem in VS2013 Update 3, Web Forms web application project. Btw, can't tell from the picture, but is your file in the root Scripts folder (and if not, did you change the path to it in VS options)?

Comment: Yep, it's in the root scripts folder where VS put it to begin with.